# Watch + much + TV

Tags: grammar

I have read the difference between much and little, yet I'm still confused about putting which one of them should appropriate in this sentence:

> I just watched ___ TV and then when to bed.

The key answer suggests "a bit of", but, will it be appropriate if I use "much"?

Both a bit of and much in my book are used to talk about a small amount or number.

Comment: "much" is _never_ associated with _"small amount or number"_. "much" means "a lot of".

Comment: _A bit of_ is informal, _a little_ would be slightly more formal. If you wanted to talk about watching TV for a long time, it would be more natural to use _a lot of TV_ than _much_.

Comment: @KateBunting I guess one could use "too much TV" but that would change the meaning slightly.

Comment: Yes, you can, and it would.

Comment: 'much' means 'a large amount of'.  Please post an official reference where it says 'a small amount of'.